# Kleisli adjunction in a (weak) 2-category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads, 2-categories

In the 2-category of 1-categories, each monad $T$ on a category $\mathcal C$ determines a Kleisli category $\mathcal{C}_T$ and the so-called [Kleisli adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category#Kleisli_adjunction) between categories $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal{C}_T$.

Let $\mathcal K$ be a (weak) 2-category, $a$ be a $0$-cell in $\mathcal K$, and $t$ be a monad on $a$. Assuming there exists a [Kleisli object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleisli+object) $a_t$, is there something like a Kleisli adjunction between $a$ and $a_t$? If yes, please describe it.

**My attempt following the hint by @KevinCarlson:** Assume that there is a Kleisli object $(f_t, \lambda)$. By applying $f_t$ to the identity map of the right $t$-module (that is $(a,t)$), you get a 1-cell from $a_t$ to $a$ that should be the right adjoint. Now, the unit should be $\lambda^{-1} \circ \eta$. But what is the counit? In **Cat**, the counit $\varepsilon_b$ would simply be $id_{t(b)}$ but I do not see how to generalize that to any 2-category $K$.

Comment: How would a 'Kleisli object' be defined?

Comment: @Berci I have added a link to the definition of a [Kleisli object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleisli+object) in my question.

Comment: You get a map from $a_t\to a$ by applying the universal property to the identity map of the right $t$-module $(a,t)$. I assume this always gives the desired adjunction, building the unit and counit out of $\lambda$, although I’ve never checked this.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Following your hint, I have edited my question with my attempt at defining this adjunction.

Comment: No, the counit of the Kleisli category is definitely not an identity map. That would imply the Kleisli category was a reflective subcategory of the base category, which is rarely true. Indeed, if we represent the Kleisli category as a full subcategory of the EM category, then the Kleisli adjunction just restricts from the EM adjunction. So the counit is the multiplication of the monad.

Comment: @KevinCarlson The multiplication?! But it does not even "typecheck".

Comment: Why not? It goes $TTx\to Tx$, and $TTx$ is $FU(Tx)$, where $F$ is the free algebra functor, $U$ the forgetful functor from the EM category, and $Tx$ is a free algebra, viewed as an object of the Kleisli category.

Comment: @KevinArlin Allow me to insist, so that I find the origin of the mistake you are pointing out: $F : C \to C_T$ maps $x$ to $x$ and $f : x \to y$ to $\eta_Y \circ f : x \to T y$. $U : C_T \to C$ maps $x$ to $T x$ and $f : x \to T y$ to $\mu_Y \circ T f : Tx \to Ty$. Therefore $\varepsilon_x$ goes from $FUx$ to $Tx$, that is from $Tx$ to $Tx$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I would try to impose the universal property of $a_t$ (being the lax colimit of the monad), to obtain the counit. But probably there is a more direct way. My monad-fu is too weak!

Comment: @Fosco Unless I misunderstood your suggestion, I believe this is exactly what I am trying to do in my attempt. But somehow I fail to build the counit. It ought to exist, so I must be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I can expand on [Kevin Arlin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31228/)'s comments in a helpful way.

The answer is yes, there is a Kleisli adjunction.

**Preamble**

I'll copy the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleisli+object) definitions to stay self-contained.

Let $K$ be a 2-category, $t:a\to a$ a monad, $(a_t,f_t,\lambda)$ a Kleisli object for $t$, meaning a representing object for the functor $K\to \newcommand\Cat{\mathbf{Cat}}\Cat\newcommand\oppd{\operatorname{.}}$ that sends an object $x$ to the right $t$-modules on $x$, $\newcommand\RMod{\operatorname{RMod}}\RMod(x,t)$.
So $a_t$ is a 0-cell, $f_t:a\to a_t$ a 1-cell, and $\lambda:f_tt\to f_t$ a 2-cell, such that 
for any right module $(r,\alpha)$, with $r:a\to x$, $\alpha : rt\to r$, there is a unique morphism $a_t\to x$ whose composite with $f_t$ (resp. $\lambda)$ is $r$ (resp. $\alpha$).

**Edit: An elementary reformulation of the definition of a Kleisli object:**

A Kleisli object for a monad $(a,t:a\to a,\mu:t^2\to t,\eta : 1_a\to t)$ consists of the data of a 0-cell $a_t$, and a right $t$-module $(f_t : a\to a_t,\lambda : f_tt\to f_t)$ on $a_t$ such that the following universality conditions are satisfied.

*Object condition:* For any right $t$-module on $x$, $(r:a\to x, \alpha : rt\to r)$, there is a **unique** morphism $g : a_t\to x$ such that 
$(r,\alpha) = (gf_t, g\oppd \lambda)$.

*Morphism condition:* For two right $t$-modules on $x$, which we know are of the form $(gf_t,g\oppd\lambda)$ and $(hf_t,h\oppd\lambda)$ by the object condition, for $g,h:a_t\to x$ and for every morphism of right $t$-modules $\beta: gf_t\to hf_t$, there is a **unique** 2-cell $\gamma : g\to h$ such that $\beta = \gamma\oppd f_t$.

**The adjoint 1-cells:**

We already have $f_t:a\to a_t$, so we need $g_t:a_t\to a$, which should correspond to a right $t$-module structure on $a$. Luckily, we already have a canonical one, $(t,\mu)$, where $\mu:t^2\to t$ is the multiplication of the monad. Thus we get a map $g_t$ from 
the universal property, such that 
$g_tf_t=t$ and $g_t\oppd\lambda = \mu$.

**The unit:**

Then the unit of the monad, $\eta:1_a\to t=g_tf_t$ is the unit of the adjunction.

**Constructing the counit:**

To construct the counit, $\epsilon : f_tg_t\to 1_{a_t}$, we need to understand 
$f_tg_t : a_t\to a_t$. However, since $a_t$ represents right modules, this morphism classifies the right module on $a_t$, $(f_tg_tf_t,f_tg_t\oppd\lambda)$, but by definition of 
$g_t$, this is equal to $(f_tt,f_t\oppd\mu)$.

Similarly, $1_{a_t}$ corresponds to the module $(f_t,\lambda)$.

Now you can check that $\lambda: f_tt\to f_t$ is a morphism of right $t$-modules between these two,
since 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
f_ttt @>f_t\oppd\mu>> f_tt \\
@V\lambda\oppd t VV @VV\lambda V\\
f_tt @>\lambda>> f_t \\ 
\end{CD}
$$
commutes, because this diagram is one of the diagrams that are required for $\lambda$ to be a multiplication making $f_t$ a $t$-module in the first place.

Thus $\lambda$ induces a morphism $\epsilon : f_tg_t\to 1_{a_t}$ satisfying $\epsilon\oppd f_t = \lambda$.

**The triangle identities:**

For the triangle identities, we now have 
$$(\epsilon\oppd f_t)(f_t\oppd \eta) = \lambda(f_t.\eta)=1_{f_t}$$ by the unit axiom of $\lambda$. For the other, we can understand 
$$(g_t\oppd \epsilon)(\eta \oppd g_t) : g_t\to g_t $$
by composing with $f_t$ to get the corresponding endomorphism of the right $t$-module $(t,\mu)$.
$$((g_t\oppd \epsilon)(\eta\oppd g_t))\oppd f_t
= (g_t\oppd \epsilon \oppd f_t)(\eta\oppd g_t\oppd f_t)
= (g_t\oppd \lambda)(\eta\oppd t)
= \mu(\eta\oppd t)
= 1_t,
$$
by the unit axiom of $\mu$. 
Since $1_t = 1_{g_t}\oppd f_t$, we conclude
$$(g_t\oppd \epsilon)(\eta\oppd g_t) = 1_{g_t},$$
as desired.

Comment: Your answer is very enlightenging. How do you define a "morphism of right t-modules" $(c, y,\rho) \to (c', y',\rho')$ ? According to the nlab, it is a $2$-cell $\beta : y \to y'$ but it does not make sense because $y : a \to c$ and $y' : a \to c'$; A $1$-cell is missing between $c$ anc $c'$.

Comment: How do you prove that $(a_t, f_t, \lambda)$ and $(a_t, f_t g_t f_t, f_t g_t . \lambda)$ are indeed right $t$-modules?

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow you when you write "Thus $\lambda$ induces a morphism $\epsilon$". I guess it might be related to the classifying morphisms you mention above, but I do not understand well this notion. So, in plain, what is the definition of $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Bob A morphism of right $t$-modules is only defined between modules on the same object $x$. So we don't need an additional $1$-cell to relate the objects.

Comment: @Bob The first one is a right $t$-module by definition of the Kleisli object as a representing object for right $t$-modules. It is by definition a right $t$-module, which you might call the universal right $t$-module. The second one is because for any morphism $\alpha : x\to y$, and any $t$-module $(x,f,l)$, $(y,\alpha f, \alpha\operatorname{.}l)$ is a right $t$-module. You should check this. This is the action of the right module functor applied to $\alpha$, $\operatorname{RMod}(\alpha,t)$, on objects (right $t$-modules).

Comment: @Bob Finally, for the definition of $\epsilon$, part of what it means for $a_t$ to represent the right $t$-module functor is that morphisms of right $t$-modules (on some object $x$) need to correspond to 2-cells between the corresponding morphisms $a_t\to x$. Given $f,g : a_t\to x$, and $\alpha : f\to g$ a 2-cell, the corresponding right modules are $(x,ff_t,f\operatorname{.}\lambda)$ and $(x,gf_t,g\operatorname{.}\lambda)$, and the morphism of $t$-modules is given by $\alpha \operatorname{.}f_t : ff_t\to gf_t$.

Comment: Since $a_t$ is a representing object, we also have a converse. Any morphism of $t$-modules $(x,ff_t,f.\lambda)\to (x,gf_t,g.\lambda)$ is of the form $\alpha.f_t$ for a unique $2$-cell $\alpha: f\to g$. Therefore $\epsilon$ is defined to be the unique morphism satisfying $\lambda = \epsilon \operatorname{.}f_t$.

Comment: Similarly, what confuses me with the definition of $\epsilon$ is that you refer on "*what it means for $a_t$ to represent the right $t$-module functor*". Maybe I can understand that. But I cannot make the link with the elementary reformulation of nLab.

Comment: @Bob The elementary reformulation is incomplete on nLab. I'll edit in a complete elementary reformulation into my top section. nLab is only talking about what happens with 1-cells, and not what happens to 2-cells.

Comment: Please! I am looking forward to the full elementary reformulation.

Comment: @Bob, edited, sorry things have been busy recently.

Comment: Thank you so much! In the *morphism condition* you wrote $\gamma : f \to h$. Don't you mean $\gamma : g \to h$?

Comment: @Bob Thanks for catching that; I've fixed it now.

Comment: In a comment above you wrote that $(f_t, \lambda)$ "*is a right $t$-module by definition of the Kleisli object as a representing object for right $t$-modules*". I could maybe understand that. But what if instead we use the elementary reformulation of the definition of a Kleisli object? I cannot deduce from it that $(f_t, \lambda)$ is a right $t$-module. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Bob I put that explicitly in my elementary reformulation. I don't think it was in nLab's version.

Comment: Well, then there must be something obvious that I am missing. For $(f_t, \lambda)$ to be a right $t$-module, there are [two equations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monad#modules) that must be checked. For instance, one of them is $\lambda \; \circ \; f_t . \eta \; = \; 1_x$. I am afraid I cannot see this written explicitly in your elementary reformulation (that is indeed much better than the one in nLab). Sorry if I am asking for the obvious, but it is really not clear for me. I'm progressing slowly through your answer.

Comment: @Bob Yes, those equations must be checked, but that's why I wrote that it forms a right $t$-module, since I'm sort of taking for granted that you know what right $t$-modules are. I guess I should have been more clear about how I was formulating it. I am formulating it as a Kleisli object is a right $t$-module subject to certain conditions, rather than it is a 0,1, and 2 cell subject to quite a few more conditions, since the language of right $t$-modules is both the most natural way to state the definition, and required for me to state the universal properties.

Comment: I have asked a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672683/non-evil-definition-of-a-kleisli-object-in-a-weak-2-category) about the definition of a Kleisli object because it seems to be more than a comment to your answer.

Comment: @Bob, yes I definitely wanted to avoid being careful about about whether I had a strict 2-category or not, which in principle should be fine, since we can strictify a non strict 2-category. The non strict version presents a fair bit of extra complexity, not least of all because nLab unhelpfully chooses not to define such a notion. I have a guess as to what the correct notion is, but I've been a bit busy recently, so I don't have time to check right now. My best guess right now is just that we replace equality with isomorphism in the *object condition* part of the definition.

Comment: Uniqueness of the 1-cell in the object condition up to unique isomorphism should follow from the morphism condition.