# Non-evil definition of a Kleisli object in a weak 2-category

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads, 2-categories, bicategories

Let $t : a \to a$ be a monad in a weak 2-category. According to nLab, the 1-dimensional universal property of a [Kleisli object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleisli+object#definition) $(f_t : a \to a_t, \lambda : f_t t \to f_t)$ is that for any right $t$-module on $x$, $(r : a \to x, \alpha : r t \to r)$, there is a unique morphism $g : a_t\to x$ such that $r = g f_t$ and $\alpha = g \cdot \lambda$.

But, in the case of a weak category, for 1-cells we do not want equalities (as it would be "evil") but we want isomorphisms instead. This means that the equality $r = g f_t$ should be replaced by an isomorphism between $r$ and $g f_t$. Now, shouldn't this isomorphism be unique? Could this be proved using the 2-dimensional universal property of a Kleisli object? Or do we need to add a coherence axiom to the definition?

P.S. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652413/kleisli-adjunction-in-a-weak-2-category/3655891#3655891) for a more detailed definition of a Kleisli object than the one in nLab.

Answer (score 2):

Although the definition of Kleisli object may appear "too strict", this is not actually the case. Kleisli objects are [flexible colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flexible+limit), which means that they are also [bicolimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit), and hence also have the pseudo universal property you describe. To answer your question, the invertible 2-cell is part of the data of the bicolimit, and is not generally unique. However, it is required to satisfy the usual coherence property inherent in the definition of a 2-dimensional colimit.